# Ajax Status/Response Data from Primefaces

Tags: ajax, primefaces

We are using Primefaces 2.x and Mojarra.  We are trying to handle one particular case where you log into our site and then delete all of the cookies.  Then click on a menu option.  What we would like to have happen is for the user to be redirected to our login screen.  The problem is that we are not using the "url" attribute, so Primefaces does a partial-page ajax call.  Which returns an empty response.

At this point, without a Session Id there is no session.  So, on the server we are in the midst of an Ajax call without a session.  If I try and do a sendRedirect it sends a 302 to the browser, but either Primefaces or the browser is ignoring it because it is part of an Ajax call.

So, what I would like to do is to put a listener on the Ajax response and look for a 302 or a change in the location.  However, I can't find a way to use the jsf.ajax.addOnEvent.  It seems that Primefaces is not using the standard JSF Ajax calls.  I looked at the AjaxStatus but all it gives me is events, no DATA and no access to the data.

I thought I could look for the JSESSIONID cookie, which the user has deleted, but when I use Javascript to print the cookies, the session id isn't printed.

So, I don't seem to be able to do a response.sendRedirect in a Session Filter because I am in the midst of an Ajax call.  And I can't detect on the client that I need to redirect the user, which I could do if I knew it was required.  And I can't seem to get any info out of Primefaces Ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

By menu you mean the p:menuItem component, right? Assuming you're using the action attribute to call a method in your managed, try using the attribute ajax="false". I use that and it works well for me.